# SQL Server ChangeTable returns inserted rows that don't exist yet

Tags: sql-server

I am using the change tracking feature of SQL Server 2014 to synchronize the internal state of my application with the database but have come across some unexpected behaviour.

My current stored procedures are based on the MSDN examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933874.aspx

What seems to happen is the SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION is an 'I' for insert with a primary key but if I join with the actual table there is no data there yet - the primary key on the change table is set but the primary key on the table itself and all the other columns are null.

This results in some parsing errors on the application side for a situation that I thought was not possible? Surely it should not report an insert if the data has not been inserted yet?

My transaction isolation level is read committed with snapshot isolation and read committed snapshot enabled as recommended by MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was not an issue with change tracking but a result of performing an inner join with another table and then an outer join against the changetable.

In this case the inner join was returning no rows (missing foreign key in the other table) and the outer join with the changetable resulted in an 'empty' insert (all columns null except for change table columns) as described in the question.

The solution was to leave the query as is but add an additional where constraint:

```
WHERE MY.PrimaryKey IS NOT NULL OR CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION = 'D'
```

This ensures that the primary key is not null when an insert or update occurs and assumes the application is tolerant of an update where no previous insert has occurred as we are essentially filtering out inserts and waiting for a subsequent update where the inner join succeeds.